# How are child actions able to have their own ViewDataDictionary instance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The `ViewData` property is of type `IDictionary<string, object>` and is declared inside the `ControllerBase` and is therefore a *per request* object.

And child actions are not separate HTTP requests.

So, ideally, a parent and child action should, under the design I am assuming above, share the same `ViewData`.

However, that seems not to be the case.

So, how is this implemented? How are child actions able to have their own `ViewData` and where is that code that creates a separate `ViewDataDictionary` instance for child actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child action has its own `ViewData` because it has its own lifecycle.

When a request is made to the main method, its controller is initialized and the action initializes its `ViewData` and begins to render its view. When `@Html.Action()` is encountered, a new instance of the controller is initialized and the child action initializes its `ViewData` and renders its view which is inserted at the placeholder specified by `@Html.Action()` (the child actions Controller and its `ViewData` is then disposed) and the main view continues to render the markup.

You can test this by creating a parameterless constructor for the controller and see that it gets initialized for each child action.

All this happens within a single HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you. So, to summarize your answer, though a single HTTP request, all child actions are executed on their own instance of the controller class, hence the separate instance of `ViewDataDictionary` for each child action.